# What is an example of a quadratic polynomial, defined on the open interval $(-3,2)$, which does not reach a maximum value?

Tags: calculus

**Question**

> What is an example of a quadratic polynomial, defined on the open
>   interval $(-3,2)$,which does not reach a maximum value.

I have no idea because I can't think it out of my head, how do we approach such questions?

Comment: How about $p(x) = x^2$?  It doesn't attain a maximum value on $(-3,2)$.

Comment: @littleO Yes you are correct, interesting. But what if its both maximum and minimum, because x^2 has a minimum in this range.

Comment: Then choose a number outside the range, like 5, and then  $(x-5)^2$ satisfies the property.

Comment: @AlexS Ah now I got it.